# Simple door phone circuit

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design

I'm a novice electronics engineer and I have a simple circuit from an analog door phone system. It's the circuit of the push button. It basically takes an input of 12 VAC so it powers 3 LEDs for the illuminated name holder. Also it takes a 9 VDC signal (audio tone) from the power supply so when the button is pressed it sends this signal to the indoor station to ring.

I want to feed 12 VAC on the signal input (9 VDC) so when the button is pressed it will send 12 VAC to the indoor station so a buzzer will ring, instead of the audio signal (9VDC).

I tried it and it works fine but will it last or something will burn out?

I forgot to mention that indoor station has also a GND connection straight from the power supply.

I added a picture of the PCB circuit with some labels. The button area has 4 pads (1, 2, 3, 4) when the button is idle pads (1-2) and (3-4) are connected in pairs. When the button is pressed all the pads are connected together. Also ignore the right 8 pads (4-4); it's for in and out other push button circuits.

If you need some more info let me know.

[image: pcb circuit]

Comment: What you've shown us about the bell device is the circuit board.  I have pretty high confidence that the circuit board can handle the higher voltage you want to feed to it.  What I don't know is whether the electronic components soldered on the circuit board can handle the voltage.  Can you list the components and describe your research on their specifications in view of the voltage you would like them to handle?